# Twit Send and Receive Twitter DMs

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to use Twit to send and receive Twitter DMs.

When I create a stream like this:

```
var stream = T.stream('user');
```

I get a 404 error. I believe this is because the user stream has been deprecated.

What stream can I use instead to send and receive DMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, you will need to use the Account Activity API to receive Direct Messages in realtime. This is a webhook-based API. Twitter has a [migration guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/migration/us-ss-migration-guide).

In summary:

1. Create an app with a listening URL for Twitter to post events to.
2. Register the webhook
3. Listen for incoming Direct Messages
4. Use the REST Direct Message API to respond.

There's also a [full tutorial](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/twitter-account-activity-tutorial-autohook) on this using a JavaScript package called `autohook`.